# Who can you bank with for environmental sustainability?

Tags: uk, money

Yesterday the theme of the [Extinction Rebellion protests](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/aug/24/extinction-rebellion-block-whitehall-in-protest-against-hmrc-and-barclays) was HMRC and Barclays over funding of fossil fuel industries.  While their focus is on the government contracts, moving individual accounts from these banks could provide additional incentives for them to behave in a more responsible way.  However, in the modern world one needs to bank with somebody.  Are there any banks that are significantly better than others in this regard, but provide the services we are accustomed to from the big ones?  I am interested in both current and saving accounts.  I am in the UK, so that is most relevant to me.

Comment: Related: [How to perform investments that benefit sustainable development?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5454/3379)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many answers to this question, and this is the best resource I know of for providing a simple answer that is specific to where you live.

https://bank.green

This provides evaluations of many banks around the world.